# Euclidean embedding of a graph based on 1-ring neighborhood distances only

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

Consider a graph $(V,E)$, $\vert V \vert = n$ and weights $\{l_{ij}\}$, where $l_{ij}>0$ iff there is an edge connecting vertices $v_i$ and $v_j$. Distances beyond the 1-ring neighborhood are not known. Think of it as triangulation mesh of a closed surface.

If $\{l_{ij}\}$ w a *complete* matrix, multidimensional scaling would yield an embedding into $\mathbb{R^3}$, such that Euclidean distances correspond to $\{l_{ij}\}$. Now, knowing on the 1-ring neighborhood only, intuitively the problem becomes ill-posed.

Still, is it possible to embed such a graph in $\mathbb{R^3}$ with $\{l_{ij}\}$ as Euclidean distances?

Comment: "If $l_{ij}$ were a complete matrix, multidimensional scaling would yield an embedding into $\mathbb{R}^3$, such that Euclidean distances correspond to $l_{ij}$.". I'm not sure why this is true. There are plenty of graphs that cannot be embedded (I assume you mean isometrically) into 3-space.